# I am not able access my component's property in the associated template in angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am calling a http post method and getting the table names from backend, in the template i am trying to display the table names using ngFor. But tablenames aren't visible.
The template is not able to access the **tNames** property. 
I am still at beginner level in angular, so there might be a basic error in the code.
`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tableList-root',
  template: `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let t of tNames">{{t}}</li>
</ul>`
  })
export class TableListComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  @Input() sName:string;
  @Input() dbName:string;
  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() passWord:string;
  public tNames:string[];
  fetchTableNames(sName,dbName,name,passWord) 
  {
      this.fetchTables(sName,dbName,name,passWord).subscribe(res=>{this.tNames=res});//tNames not accesible in the template
  }
  fetchTables(sName,dbName,name,passWord): Observable<string[]>
  {
    let data = { "serverName": sName, "databaseName": dbName, "userName": name, "passWord": passWord };
    const headers = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    let request = "{" + JSON.stringify(data).slice(1, -1) + "}";
     return this.http.post('http://localhost/UtilityApp/api/Utility/getTableList',
        request,
        headers
    ).map(response=>{return response as string[]})
  }`
```

PFA a snapshot in the below url: -"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgl2c.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgl2c.png"

Comment: are you sure, that the POST request for "getTableList" should be POST instead of GET? And instead of string concat  (" { + data + }") you should be able to pass the data object directly - so you don't need the request variable. And why is your component template called "app-root" but your component 'TableListComponent'?

Comment: yes, its a post request and I am able to get the table names in postman, and if I use alert in the subscribe, I am able to see the table names. Selector name is a typo

Comment: @TheHeadRush I have pasted my code

Answer (score -2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tableList-root',
  template: `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let t of tNames">{{t}}</li>
</ul>`
  })
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  @Input() sName:string;
  @Input() dbName:string;
  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() passWord:string;
  public tNames:string[];

  ngOnInit(){
   fetchTableNames(sName,dbName,name,passWord) 
  {
      this.fetchTables(sName,dbName,name,passWord).subscribe(res=>{this.tNames=res});//tNames not accesible in the template
  }
  fetchTables(sName,dbName,name,passWord): Observable<string[]>
  {
    let data = { "serverName": sName, "databaseName": dbName, "userName": name, "passWord": passWord };
    const headers = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    let request = "{" + JSON.stringify(data).slice(1, -1) + "}";
     return this.http.post('http://localhost/UtilityApp/api/Utility/getTableList',
        request,
        headers
    ).map(response=>{return response as string[]})
  }`

  }

  }
```

// Please import OnInit from angular/core

Comment: can you please provide the exact code snippet which I should paste in my code, so that template is able to access the property. I am not able to figure out what should be done in ngOnInit(), thanks!!

Comment: @sonusinghal getting an error , cannot find 'fetchTableNames'